# Strip list of lists that have single quotes

Tags: python

I am creating a list of validation losses for a regression model and they are in this format:

```
mylist = ['[72.49191836014535]', '[83.83327374257702]', '[72.48327325617225]', 
 '[66.98897377186994]', '[71.13875892170039]', '[64.3820106481657]', 
 '[73.28287317220448]', '[79.7119315804787]', '[79.55777844179023]', 
 '[89.62320741326292]']
```

how can I put them in a simple list in order to calculate average/deviation?

Comment: Is your list really a list of strings that look like lists? Did you make this list? If so, you should really fix it at the source.

Comment: I agree with @MarkMeyer entirely, and I wish more people would point out that sort of thing, rather than just jumping to getting an answer of copy/paste code accepted.

Answer (score 0):

### Use this:

```
import ast
[ast.literal_eval(i)[0] for i in mylist]
```

---

**Full Example with `numpy`:**

```
import numpy as np, ast

mylist = ['[72.49191836014535]', '[83.83327374257702]', '[72.48327325617225]', 
          '[66.98897377186994]', '[71.13875892170039]', '[64.3820106481657]', 
          '[73.28287317220448]', '[79.7119315804787]', '[79.55777844179023]', 
          '[89.62320741326292]']

clean_list = np.array([ast.literal_eval(i)[0] for i in mylist])
#array([72.49191836, 83.83327374, 72.48327326, 66.98897377, 71.13875892,
#       64.38201065, 73.28287317, 79.71193158, 79.55777844, 89.62320741])

clean_list.mean()
75.34
```

---

**Full Example WITHOUT `numpy`:**

```
mylist = ['[72.49191836014535]', '[83.83327374257702]', '[72.48327325617225]', 
          '[66.98897377186994]', '[71.13875892170039]', '[64.3820106481657]', 
          '[73.28287317220448]', '[79.7119315804787]', '[79.55777844179023]', 
          '[89.62320741326292]']

clean_list = [ast.literal_eval(i)[0] for i in mylist]
#[72.49191836, 83.83327374, 72.48327326, 66.98897377, 71.13875892,
#       64.38201065, 73.28287317, 79.71193158, 79.55777844, 89.62320741]

average_list = sum(clean_list) / len(clean_list)
75.34
```

Comment: You should use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

Without using eval:

```py
import numpy as np

mylist = ['[72.49191836014535]', '[83.83327374257702]', '[72.48327325617225]', 
 '[66.98897377186994]', '[71.13875892170039]', '[64.3820106481657]', 
 '[73.28287317220448]', '[79.7119315804787]', '[79.55777844179023]', 
 '[89.62320741326292]']

mylist = np.array([float(i[1:-1]) for i in mylist])

mylist.mean()
```

**Output:**

```py
75.34939993083671
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove [ and ] and then convert values to float:

```
import regex as re

mylist = [
    "[72.49191836014535]",
    "[83.83327374257702]",
    "[72.48327325617225]",
    "[66.98897377186994]",
    "[71.13875892170039]",
    "[64.3820106481657]",
    "[73.28287317220448]",
    "[79.7119315804787]",
    "[79.55777844179023]",
    "[89.62320741326292]",
]

data = [float(re.sub(r"[\[\]]", "", v)) for v in mylist]
```

Output:

```
[72.49191836014535,
 83.83327374257702,
 72.48327325617225,
 66.98897377186994,
 71.13875892170039,
 64.3820106481657,
 73.28287317220448,
 79.7119315804787,
 79.55777844179023,
 89.62320741326292]
```

Answer (score -2):

Another solution, similar to above:

```
from statistics import mean 

mylist = ['[72.49191836014535]', '[83.83327374257702]', '[72.48327325617225]', 
          '[66.98897377186994]', '[71.13875892170039]', '[64.3820106481657]', 
          '[73.28287317220448]', '[79.7119315804787]', '[79.55777844179023]', 
          '[89.62320741326292]']

list = [ast.literal_eval(i)[0] for i in mylist]
print(mean(list))
```

result:

```
75.3493999308367
```

Comment: At least use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `eval()`.

Answer (score -4):

Expanding on Makis and Eric Day above:

```
import statistics

data = [ eval(a)[0] for a in mylist ]

# collate stats wanted for printing
stats = [sum, statistics.mean, statistics.stdev, statistics.variance]
for stat in stats:
    print(stat.___name____, stat(data))
```